# Assign unique value to datacenter based on launch month (min)? SQL question

Tags: sql, group-by

I have a table that shows customer usage on datacenters per month. I want to column called Cohort_Month for each month (M1, M2, M3, etc) based on the earliest launch month.

Business Goal: I am trying to compare how datacenter usage scaled based on their first start month (M1) and so forth...

Sample data:

```
+----------+------------+-----------+----------------------+
| Customer | Datacenter |   Month   | Total Credits Burned |
+----------+------------+-----------+----------------------+
| Apple    | DC1        | 12 / 2019 |                  618 |
| Google   | DC1        | 12 / 2019 |                  463 |
| Apple    | DC1        | 01 / 2019 |                  961 |
| Google   | DC1        | 01 / 2019 |                  590 |
| BCG      | DC5        | 11 / 2018 |                  729 |
| Mckinsey | DC5        | 11 / 2018 |                  194 |
| Bain     | DC5        | 11 / 2018 |                  652 |
| BCG      | DC5        | 12 / 2018 |                  952 |
| Mckinsey | DC5        | 12 / 2018 |                  477 |
| Bain     | DC5        | 12 / 2018 |                  917 |
| BCG      | DC5        | 01 / 2019 |                  618 |
| Mckinsey | DC5        | 01 / 2019 |                  350 |
| Bain     | DC5        | 01 / 2019 |                  378 |
| BCG      | DC5        | 02 / 2019 |                  302 |
| Mckinsey | DC5        | 02 / 2019 |                  838 |
| Bain     | DC5        | 02 / 2019 |                  500 |
+----------+------------+-----------+----------------------+
```

I am trying to get the following output:

```
+----------+------------+-----------+----------------------+--------------+
| Customer | Datacenter |   Month   | Total Credits Burned | Cohort_Month |
+----------+------------+-----------+----------------------+--------------+
| Apple    | DC1        | 12 / 2019 |                  618 | M1           |
| Google   | DC1        | 12 / 2019 |                  463 | M1           |
| Apple    | DC1        | 01 / 2019 |                  961 | M2           |
| Google   | DC1        | 01 / 2019 |                  590 | M2           |
| BCG      | DC5        | 11 / 2018 |                  729 | M1           |
| Mckinsey | DC5        | 11 / 2018 |                  194 | M1           |
| Bain     | DC5        | 11 / 2018 |                  652 | M1           |
| BCG      | DC5        | 12 / 2018 |                  952 | M2           |
| Mckinsey | DC5        | 12 / 2018 |                  477 | M2           |
| Bain     | DC5        | 12 / 2018 |                  917 | M2           |
| BCG      | DC5        | 01 / 2019 |                  618 | M3           |
| Mckinsey | DC5        | 01 / 2019 |                  350 | M3           |
| Bain     | DC5        | 01 / 2019 |                  378 | M3           |
| BCG      | DC5        | 02 / 2019 |                  302 | M4           |
| Mckinsey | DC5        | 02 / 2019 |                  838 | M4           |
| Bain     | DC5        | 02 / 2019 |                  500 | M4           |
+----------+------------+-----------+----------------------+--------------+
```

- Slight edit from the original post
  ** Appreciate any tips!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

THIS ANSWERS THE ORIGINAL VERSION OF THE QUESTION.

You seem to want `row_number()`:

```
select Datacenter, Month,
       row_number() over (partition by Datacenter order by Month) as cohort_month
from sampledata;
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your comment! Your query worked for my original question; however, I modified it slightly to include customers. I'm still looking to assign each datacenter's launch month as M1, up to M(N), where N = maximum number of months since launch. Any tips?

Comment: @RobL . . . New questions should be asked as *new* questions, not as edits to existing questions that have already been answered.

Comment: Hi, thanks for feedback; duly noted. I will ask revised question later. Thanks for assistance!